# How to shift 3rd yaxis leftward in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plot, made using Plotly, that contains 3 y-axis, of which 2 are on the left side.

The ones on the left side overlap and looks like this:

[image]

I have tried changing the `position` argument, but it takes values between 0 and 1 and only shifts the y-axis towards the opposite side of the plot.

The [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/) suggests (under the title "Shift Axes by a Specific Number of Pixels") that I should use the `shift` argument but I get an error:

```
Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.layout.YAxis: 'shift'
```

All I want is to shift the axis titled `yaxis2` a little left so that neither the labels nor the values overlap.

PS: Due to a lack of proper words, my research about this issue on the internet did not yield any tangible results, so if this question is already asked and answered on the internet, including Stackoverflow, I would appreciate it if you can navigate me towards there.

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to provide a reproducible question, especially in a question where there are so very many ways you could have your data presented to create this graph.

In this answer, I started with an example plot from Plotly's website and modified it to show you one of the many ways you could have multiple axes in Plotly with Python.

In the three traces, I named the y-axes. I used those names in `fig.update_layout`. You can read more about that [here](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scatter.html) and [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/). You can also see how closely this aligns with how this is done in JS in [this example](https://plotly.com/javascript/multiple-axes/).

- The first y-axis maintains the defaults, attached to the x-axis on the left side.
- The second y-axis is detached from the x-axis, and positioned at "0". That position is the using the domain. The domain is an arbitrary range (default is [0, 1]) that represents the space within the x-axis.

In the update to the layout for the x-axis, I changed the domain to [.15, .9]. This pushed the first y-axis to `position = .15` because it's attached to the x-axis, thus separating the first two y-axes.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create figure with multiple y-axes
fig = make_subplots()

# Add traces, the first two are pretty much copied from Plotly's site
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = [1, 2, 3], y = [40, 50, 60], name="yaxis data", yaxis = "y"))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = [2, 3, 4], y = [4, 5, 6], name = "yaxis2 data", yaxis = "y2"))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = [1, 4, 3], y = [602, 500, 120], name = "yaxis3 data", yaxis = "y3"))


# add titles, position axes
fig.update_layout(
    title_text = "Triple Y Axis Example",
    yaxis = dict(title = "first axis"),                                 # yaxis = "y", attached to x-axis
    yaxis2 = dict(position = 0, title = "second axis",                  # yaxis = "y2", pos 0, free from x-axis
                  side = "left", anchor = "free", overlaying = "y"),
    yaxis3 = dict(title = "third axis", side = "right", anchor = "x",   # yaxis = "y3", attached to x-axis
                  overlaying = "y"),
    xaxis = dict(title = "x-axis", domain = [.15, .9])  # domain so that the y-axis labels are outside of the plot
)

fig.show()
```

[image]